# How to set the big table within page margins?

Tags: tables, margins

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,etoolbox}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan,}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[vmargin=1.0in, left=1in, right=1.in,  
            footskip=2.0cm, % footskip margin
           ]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{llllllllll}
\multirow{3}{*}{Chrom Length} & \multicolumn{9}{l}{Success Rate (\%)} \\
 & \multicolumn{3}{l}{SRP 1} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{SRP 2} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{SRP 3} \\
 & Contr.   Opr. & Slice   Cross. & Comb. & Contr.   Opr. & Slice   Cross. & Comb. & Contr.   Opr. & Slice   Cross. & Comb. \\
11 & 40 & 88 & 85 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 3 & 8 \\
\multirow{3}{*}{15} & 56 & 94 & 97 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 10 & 5 \\
 & 61 & 99 & 100 & 0 & 7 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 13 \\
 & 62 & 100 & 98 & 0 & 23 & 21 & 5 & 8 & 12 \\
\multirow{3}{*}{27} & 58 & 97 & 100 & 0 & 38 & 37 & 3 & 13 & 14 \\
 & 65 & 100 & 98 & 2 & 41 & 44 & 4 & 14 & 13 \\
 & 69 & 99 & 99 & 6 & 52 & 42 & 7 & 7 & 10 \\
39 & 72 & 97 & 99 & 10 & 49 & 57 & 7 & 8 & 8 \\
43 & 74 & 94 & 96 & 7 & 57 & 59 & 3 & 12 & 8 \\
47 & 66 & 94 & 95 & 9 & 49 & 62 & 5 & 11 & 13 \\
51 & 79 & 97 & 94 & 10 & 62 & 61 & 5 & 8 & 9 \\
55 & 80 & 96 & 97 & 11 & 70 & 58 & 5 & 7 & 6 \\
59 & 73 & 96 & 98 & 12 & 59 & 51 & 0 & 7 & 10 \\
63 & 75 & 98 & 95 & 17 & 60 & 68 & 3 & 8 & 7 \\
67 & 74 & 99 & 96 & 21 & 66 & 63 & 4 & 8 & 4 \\
71 & 78 & 98 & 93 & 20 & 59 & 68 & 0 & 3 & 4 \\
75 & 75 & 96 & 96 & 16 & 61 & 72 & 3 & 3 & 9 \\
79 & 78 & 100 & 99 & 16 & 61 & 58 & 1 & 8 & 8 \\
83 & 69 & 96 & 98 & 18 & 74 & 71 & 1 & 5 & 11 \\
87 & 77 & 94 & 98 & 24 & 70 & 56 & 1 & 7 & 9 \\
91 & 72 & 97 & 92 & 20 & 67 & 68 & 4 & 5 & 4 \\
95 & 76 & 97 & 93 & 20 & 52 & 61 & 0 & 7 & 8 \\
99 & 82 & 91 & 95 & 24 & 68 & 63 & 4 & 4 & 2 \\
103 & 77 & 94 & 98 & 25 & 56 & 61 & 1 & 7 & 6 \\
Average & 70.33 & 96.29 & 96.21 & 12.00 & 50.04 & 50.29 & 3.25 & 7.46 & 8.38
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: The `geometry`-package  options `vmargin=1.0in, left=1in, right=1.in` may be written more compactly as `margin=1in`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

(red lines show page layout)

- Column headers are to wide, write thwo in two lines!
- By use of `tblr` of `tabularray` with libraries `booktabs` and  `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in, 
            footskip=2.0cm, % footskip margin
           ]{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}

\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=2.0}]}
                            *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=3.0}]}
                            *{6}{X[c, si={table-format=2.0}]}
                        @{} },
             cell{2}{2,5,8} = {c=3}{c},
             row{1-3,Z} = {guard,b},
             rowsep = 1pt
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=3]{l}    Chrome Length
    &   \SetCell[c=9]{c}  Source rate
        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &                   \\
    \cmidrule{2-10}
    &   SRP 1 
        &   &   &   SRP 2
                    &   &   &   SRP 2
                                &   &                   \\    
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-4}
    \cmidrule[lr]{5-7}
    \cmidrule[lr]{8-10}
    & Contr. Opr.   & Slice   Cross.    &  Comb.
    & Contr. Opr.   & Slice   Cross.    &  Comb.
    & Contr. Opr.   & Slice   Cross.    &  Comb.        \\
    \midrule
11  & 40    & 88    & 85    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 5     & 3     & 8     \\
    \midrule[dashed, 0.15pt]
    & 56    & 94    & 97    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 4     & 10    & 5     \\
15  & 61    & 99    & 100   & 0     & 7     & 6     & 3     & 6     & 13    \\
    & 62    & 100   & 98    & 0     & 23    & 21    & 5     & 8     & 12    \\
    \midrule[dashed, 0.15pt]
    & 58    & 97    & 100   & 0     & 38    & 37    & 3     & 13    & 14    \\
27  & 65    & 100   & 98    & 2     & 41    & 44    & 4     & 14    & 13    \\
    & 69    & 99    & 99    & 6     & 52    & 42    & 7     & 7     & 10    \\
    \midrule[dashed, 0.15pt]
39  & 72    & 97    & 99    & 10    & 49    & 57    & 7     & 8     & 8     \\
43  & 74    & 94    & 96    & 7     & 57    & 59    & 3     & 12    & 8     \\
47  & 66    & 94    & 95    & 9     & 49    & 62    & 5     & 11    & 13    \\
51  & 79    & 97    & 94    & 10    & 62    & 61    & 5     & 8     & 9     \\
55  & 80    & 96    & 97    & 11    & 70    & 58    & 5     & 7     & 6     \\
59  & 73    & 96    & 98    & 12    & 59    & 51    & 0     & 7     & 10    \\
63  & 75    & 98    & 95    & 17    & 60    & 68    & 3     & 8     & 7     \\
67  & 74    & 99    & 96    & 21    & 66    & 63    & 4     & 8     & 4     \\
71  & 78    & 98    & 93    & 20    & 59    & 68    & 0     & 3     & 4     \\
75  & 75    & 96    & 96    & 16    & 61    & 72    & 3     & 3     & 9     \\
79  & 78    & 100   & 99    & 16    & 61    & 58    & 1     & 8     & 8     \\
83  & 69    & 96    & 98    & 18    & 74    & 71    & 1     & 5     & 11    \\
87  & 77    & 94    & 98    & 24    & 70    & 56    & 1     & 7     & 9     \\
91  & 72    & 97    & 92    & 20    & 67    & 68    & 4     & 5     & 4     \\
95  & 76    & 97    & 93    & 20    & 52    & 61    & 0     & 7     & 8     \\
99  & 82    & 91    & 95    & 24    & 68    & 63    & 4     & 4     & 2     \\
103 & 77    & 94    & 98    & 25    & 56    & 61    & 1     & 7     & 6     \\
Average 
    & 70.33 & 96.29 & 96.21 & 12.00 & 50.04 & 50.29 & 3.25  & 7.46  & 8.38  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that employs the machinery of the [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package to assure that the table fits within the width of the text block. By using the `X` column type in all ten columns, LaTeX can insert line breaks in cells if and when needed.

Separately, I would also employ the macros of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package to provide some additional visual structure, both in the table's header rows and in the body of the table. See, in particular, the use of `\addlinespace` directives in the following code to provide some (hopefully helpful) visual rhythm.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
  \graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{%amsfonts, % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
            amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,etoolbox}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl}
\urlstyle{same}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, 
            filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan}

\usepackage[margin=1in, footskip=2cm]{geometry}

%% New code
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash[b]{%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\hsize}@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{A ten-column table\strut}
\label{tab:my-table}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L *{9}{C} @{}}
\toprule
\mytab{Chrom Length} & \multicolumn{9}{c@{}}{Success Rate (\%)}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-10}
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{SRP 1} 
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{SRP 2} 
 & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{SRP 3} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10}
 & Contr.\ Opr. & Slice Cross. & Comb. 
 & Contr.\ Opr. & Slice Cross. & Comb. 
 & Contr.\ Opr. & Slice Cross. & Comb. \\
\midrule
11 & 40 &  88 &  85 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 5 &  3 &  8 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{3}{*}{15} 
   & 56 &  94 &  97 &  0 &  0 &  0 & 4 & 10 &  5 \\
   & 61 &  99 & 100 &  0 &  7 &  6 & 3 &  6 & 13 \\
   & 62 & 100 &  98 &  0 & 23 & 21 & 5 &  8 & 12 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{3}{*}{27} 
   & 58 &  97 & 100 &  0 & 38 & 37 & 3 & 13 & 14 \\
   & 65 & 100 &  98 &  2 & 41 & 44 & 4 & 14 & 13 \\
   & 69 &  99 &  99 &  6 & 52 & 42 & 7 &  7 & 10 \\
\addlinespace
39 & 72 &  97 &  99 & 10 & 49 & 57 & 7 &  8 &  8 \\
43 & 74 &  94 &  96 &  7 & 57 & 59 & 3 & 12 &  8 \\
47 & 66 &  94 &  95 &  9 & 49 & 62 & 5 & 11 & 13 \\
51 & 79 &  97 &  94 & 10 & 62 & 61 & 5 &  8 &  9 \\
55 & 80 &  96 &  97 & 11 & 70 & 58 & 5 &  7 &  6 \\
\addlinespace
59 & 73 &  96 &  98 & 12 & 59 & 51 & 0 &  7 & 10 \\
63 & 75 &  98 &  95 & 17 & 60 & 68 & 3 &  8 &  7 \\
67 & 74 &  99 &  96 & 21 & 66 & 63 & 4 &  8 &  4 \\
71 & 78 &  98 &  93 & 20 & 59 & 68 & 0 &  3 &  4 \\
75 & 75 &  96 &  96 & 16 & 61 & 72 & 3 &  3 &  9 \\
\addlinespace
79 & 78 & 100 &  99 & 16 & 61 & 58 & 1 &  8 &  8 \\
83 & 69 &  96 &  98 & 18 & 74 & 71 & 1 &  5 & 11 \\
87 & 77 &  94 &  98 & 24 & 70 & 56 & 1 &  7 &  9 \\
91 & 72 &  97 &  92 & 20 & 67 & 68 & 4 &  5 &  4 \\
95 & 76 &  97 &  93 & 20 & 52 & 61 & 0 &  7 &  8 \\
\addlinespace
99 & 82 &  91 &  95 & 24 & 68 & 63 & 4 &  4 &  2 \\
103 & 77 & 94 &  98 & 25 & 56 & 61 & 1 &  7 &  6 \\
\midrule
Average & 70.33 & 96.29 & 96.21 & 12.00 & 50.04 & 50.29 & 3.25 & 7.46 & 8.38 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd not use `\multirow` for the 15 and 27 groups: the output would be very ambiguous. An empty cell after one in the first column will be interpreted as “repeat the previous value”.

I'd also use `siunitx`, besides `booktabs`, in order to improve the appearance. The `\splitcell` command helps in setting complex cells; the `*`-variant also applies `\smash`.

Provide a caption text: your readers will appreciate.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
  vmargin=1.0in,
  left=1in,
  right=1.in,  
  footskip=2.0cm, % footskip margin
]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,etoolbox}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan,}

\urlstyle{same}

\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\NewDocumentCommand{\splitcell}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\smash}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{A caption here, please}
\label{tab:my-table}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  @{}
}
\toprule
\splitcell*{Chrom \\ Length} & \multicolumn{9}{c}{Success Rate (\%)} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-10}
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{SRP 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{SRP 2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{SRP 3} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10}
 & \splitcell{Contr. \\ Opr.} & \splitcell{Slice \\ Cross.} & {Comb.}
 & \splitcell{Contr. \\ Opr.} & \splitcell{Slice \\ Cross.} & {Comb.}
 & \splitcell{Contr. \\ Opr.} & \splitcell{Slice \\ Cross.} & {Comb.} \\
\midrule
11 & 40 & 88 & 85 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 3 & 8 \\
15 & 56 & 94 & 97 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 10 & 5 \\
 & 61 & 99 & 100 & 0 & 7 & 6 & 3 & 6 & 13 \\
 & 62 & 100 & 98 & 0 & 23 & 21 & 5 & 8 & 12 \\
27 & 58 & 97 & 100 & 0 & 38 & 37 & 3 & 13 & 14 \\
 & 65 & 100 & 98 & 2 & 41 & 44 & 4 & 14 & 13 \\
 & 69 & 99 & 99 & 6 & 52 & 42 & 7 & 7 & 10 \\
39 & 72 & 97 & 99 & 10 & 49 & 57 & 7 & 8 & 8 \\
43 & 74 & 94 & 96 & 7 & 57 & 59 & 3 & 12 & 8 \\
47 & 66 & 94 & 95 & 9 & 49 & 62 & 5 & 11 & 13 \\
51 & 79 & 97 & 94 & 10 & 62 & 61 & 5 & 8 & 9 \\
55 & 80 & 96 & 97 & 11 & 70 & 58 & 5 & 7 & 6 \\
59 & 73 & 96 & 98 & 12 & 59 & 51 & 0 & 7 & 10 \\
63 & 75 & 98 & 95 & 17 & 60 & 68 & 3 & 8 & 7 \\
67 & 74 & 99 & 96 & 21 & 66 & 63 & 4 & 8 & 4 \\
71 & 78 & 98 & 93 & 20 & 59 & 68 & 0 & 3 & 4 \\
75 & 75 & 96 & 96 & 16 & 61 & 72 & 3 & 3 & 9 \\
79 & 78 & 100 & 99 & 16 & 61 & 58 & 1 & 8 & 8 \\
83 & 69 & 96 & 98 & 18 & 74 & 71 & 1 & 5 & 11 \\
87 & 77 & 94 & 98 & 24 & 70 & 56 & 1 & 7 & 9 \\
91 & 72 & 97 & 92 & 20 & 67 & 68 & 4 & 5 & 4 \\
95 & 76 & 97 & 93 & 20 & 52 & 61 & 0 & 7 & 8 \\
99 & 82 & 91 & 95 & 24 & 68 & 63 & 4 & 4 & 2 \\
103 & 77 & 94 & 98 & 25 & 56 & 61 & 1 & 7 & 6 \\
\midrule
{Average} & {70.33} & {96.29} & {96.21} & {12.00} & {50.04} & {50.29} & {3.25} & {7.46} & {8.38} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]